# How many LC oscillators can you easily fit on a single chip?

Tags: circuit-design, oscillator, fabrication

I recently read [this interesting blog post](https://blog.normalcomputing.ai/posts/2023-11-09-thermodynamic-inversion/thermo-inversion.html) about 'thermodynamic computing' that tickled my fancy.

The TLDR version is that the authors designed and built a circuit that can perform matrix inversion using a bunch of coupled LC oscillators (one oscillator for each dimension of the square matrix you'd like to invert).

The mathematical details are interesting in themselves, but I can more or less understand those. What I know much less (read: almost nothing) about is the fabrication of LC oscillators, and impediments to miniaturisation. The blog post demonstrates a successful proof of concept, showing that an 8x8 matrix can (approximately) be inverted using such an approach - I've added a screenshot of the circuit from the blog post below, with the oscillators highlighted.

[image: Screenshot of the circuit from the blog post, with the oscillators highlighted]

How hard would it be be scale such an approach up, to e.g. a 10000x10000 matrix (thereby requiring 10^8 LC circuits, and completely too many couplings between them)? What is the current state of the art, and what kinds of problems will one have to deal with, fabrication wise? Comments on cost and pointers to relevant literature are also welcome!

Comment: I'm not an expert on this and I don't have a concrete answer, but inductors are some of the hardest things to miniaturize on-chip. Dimensions are in the 100's of um at least, AFAIK. An artificial inductor made with an op-amp might be smaller, but I don't know if it would work in this application. Probably some other circuit that happens to work according to equivalent differential equations would be a better solution.

Comment: @ThePhoton Thanks! You're definitely more of an expert than I am ;)  Can you expand on why it's hard to miniaturize inductors on-chip?

Comment: @MartinC. Just consider the physics of inductors. Capacitors you can make small by using thinner dielectric to offset the reduced area, but for inductors, all you can do is increase the number of turns to offset reduced area--and more turns take up more space too, especially when you have a limited number of metal layers in your process.

Comment: Capacitors don't miniaturize very well either. Just listen to how the layout engineers scream when you want more than a few picofarads in a circuit. For either one to make them compact you want to use special materials (with high permeability for inductors and permittivity for capacitors) and these materials aren't compatible with semiconductor processes.

Comment: Offhand, monolithic inductors are practical for single to 10s of GHz, with mediocre Q factors (5-15), and take up a whole lot of space (preferably on upper metal layers, with many oxide layers inbetween, to give some room for fields around the conductors). They're just practical for IF and RF tuning, matching and filtering in microwave circuits, but you'll have a hard time getting millions on one chip.

Comment: These comments have all been very informative, thank you.